# Interpreter in C#: Create an Independent Callstack

Tags: c#, parsing, interpreter

For the purposes of this question, I'm writing a simplistic interpreter in C# with function call support. It's just

```
a = x(1, 'x', y: z());
```

Now, I've parsed this expression into an AST of approximately this shape and form:

```
AssignmentExpression
  VariableReferenceExpression
  FunctionCallExpression
    Int64ConstantExpression
```

When I go "full Java" on this and traverse the tree with the `ExpressionEvaluatorVisitor`, I need to somehow invoke the functions from all the `FunctionCallExpression`s. An obvious option will be to map function names to static methods in some arbitrary class and then just use `MethodInfo.Invoke()` on the correct `MethodInfo` instance. This, however, will totally mix up my very own call stack with that of the interpreted expression.

Is there any way to somehow create an "alternate" callstack in .NET or is there any other way to distinguish two independent callstacks?

Comment: So I take it that the code you're interpreting isn't actually C# code; you're trying to translate it into C# code that can then be compiled and run?  Or are you just writing your own C# compiler as an exercise?

Comment: @Servy I'm not writing a _compiler_, just an interpreter of some other language.

Comment: It sounds like he's writing an interpreter for a different language, but the interpreter is written in C#.

Comment: @AntonGogolev The idea of saying that you plan to map `z()` to a `MethodInfo` and then `Invoke` that implies that you're trying to create a scripting language based on the syntax of C#, and that the language you're writing an interpreter for is in fact C# (possibly with slight modifications).  If so, you're best bet is likely to translate whatever valid code in your language into valid C# code (if a translation is necessary) and then just let the C# compiler compile and run the whole thing.

Comment: @Servy Not sure I get you correctly.  What I'm parsing is not C#, but some random DSL. In this DSL I want to have a "standard library" of sorts, which I wanted to implement inside the parser proper. For example, "co

Comment: It is always possible to convert recursion into a loop and a stack. See the answer that has appeared so far.

Comment: Fatfingered. @Servy Not sure I get you correctly.  What I'm parsing is not C#, but some random DSL. In this DSL I want to have a "standard library" of sorts, which I wanted to implement inside the parser proper. For example, "concat()", "reverse()", etc. - are all good candidates for an "stdlib". If they get called via Invoke() and there happens to be a runtime error, the callstack will be "polluted" with calls to parsers' internals, which I don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interpreter is performing tasks on behalf of the interpreted code, so the execution of the interpreter is inherently coupled to the interpreted code. However, you could simulate a call stack (which will be useful for debugging the interpreted program, and necessary if you want to support reentrant functions in the interpreted language) by simply defining a class called `CallStackElement` with fields such as `MethodName`, `ParameterList`, `LocalVariables`, and so on, and have a `Stack<CallStackElement>`. Whenever the interpreted code calls a function (whether it is a user-defined function or a library function), add an element to this stack, and pop it when the function is done. If you support user-defined functions, local variables and parameters should be looked up in the topmost element of the call stack.